# Struck in foreach while looping around GridViewRow 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView` because

> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I don't know why it is appearing. I've google it too but didn't get enough help.
Here is my code

```
HyperLink A;
foreach (GridView row in GridView2)
{
    A=(HyperLink)row.FindControl("hyp");
    A.NavigateUrl += A.Text;
}
```

**Points about Code**

I've a GridView where i'm showing some hyperlinks when user click on a link it will take him to the desired location through query string

Comment: While looping you need to use `GridViewRow` not `GridView` change it to this `foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)`

Comment: Yeah it was GridViewRow. In a haste i forgot to put Row. and thanks for your time. It works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView2` is not a collection. `foreach` work only for `Collections` that implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`. In your case you want to iterate over `GridView2.Rows` and not `GridView2`. So your foreach shoulb be like

```
         foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
         {
             A=(HyperLink)row.FindControl("hyp");
            A.NavigateUrl += A.Text;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use GridView2.Rows instead of GridView.

 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
     {
         A=(HyperLink)row.FindControl("hyp");
         A.NavigateUrl += A.Text;
     }
```